# PCA : how to cluster data to differenciate my data the most while considering their groups

Tags: r, pca, k-means, model-based-clustering

I have to do a PCA in R for a project, but I have 300 data in 15 differents groups, and I want to find the reduced space which gives me the most variability between the groups and cluster my data in their own group ( so not between all the data) so I can do an analysis later while using these variables (I have 4000 very similar variables).

I know how to do the analysis when I want to cluster data that are not already in a group, but I don't know how to do it when I want to find out which variable can separate my groups the best.

The objective is that I use the reduced space that explain the most of the group variability to use them to do analysis, to observe if the data groups are really significantly different when I consider all the data, but I'm not sure if it's actually something possible to do with a ACP.

Thank you!

[image: If it makes more sense, I want to see a result like that plot, but the cluster represent the groups I already have to see if they go upon each other, or if they are clearly different. I did a plot before that did not differenciate my data as their group and it was a mess, all mixed up]

Comment: Have a look at ICA. PCA looks at maximizing the variance while ICA search for the best split

Comment: I am not sure what method by itself does clustering and discriminant analysis together. Maybe a custom autoencoder? Anyway, [here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/fd18c1f1dd3f95490ed3203e6585c631) is a Python gist which performs linear discriminant analysis followed by k-means clustering.

Comment: You might want to change the title because my understanding is that you do *not* need to cluster the data, rather you have clusters already given?

Answer (score 0):

There are classical discriminant coordinates, closely related to Fisher's discriminant analysis, that project the data on a low (e.g., 2-d) hyperplane in such a way that ratio between the variation between class means and the variation within classes is maximum. This will give you an, in a well defined sense, optimal 2-d plot separating the clusters. There are also some versions of this taking robustness against outliers into account.

This is implemented in the R-functions `plotcluster` and `discrcoord` in my `fpc` package, see also references on the help pages.